# multilevel group analysis with random slopes in R

Tags: multilevel-analysis, sem

I am trying to perform a multilevel group analysis with random slopes (two groups).
I am trained to use `sem()` in the `lavaan` package in R for any mediation or SEM.

But it seems like it is impossible to conduct "random slope" models using `sem()`
Do you know any other functions or software with which I can perform them?